# Multi-port, 100W @ 5A, USB-C charger

Tags: usb, power-supply, hub

I've been looking to replace a couple [Anker PowerPort](https://www.anker.com/products/A2123113)-style 5-port USB-chargers around my house (computer desk, entryway table, laboratory workbench) with ones into which I can plug my [15″ Macbook Pro](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/).

Now, the MBP tops out at 4.35 amps @ 20V (which the [Apple-branded 87W power-adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MNF82LL/A/87w-usb-c-power-adapter) provides); but the [fastest Anker USB-C product](https://www.anker.com/products/A2014111) I could find only supports 30W on a single port (and only *has* a single port, at that), while also having [serious production issues](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2UR46XXKO1HKW) that disindicate it for everyday use — while the [only multi-port product](https://www.anker.com/products/A2052111) with USB-C doesn't even support power-delivery (providing only the base 5V, for a total of 15W!)

So, the search continues. I need:

1. A **multi-port** … *(ideally, many-port — 6+ would be great; but minimum of 4)*
2. … **USB-C** … *(≥4 USB-C ports; though a couple 5V USB-A ports wouldn't go amiss)*
3. … **100W** charger. *(i.e. supports USB-PD's 20V mode)*

What I *don't* need is:

- A **hub**, *(I don't need data pass-through of any sort, just wall-charging of multiple USB-C devices simultaneously wherever I happen to be in the house)*
- nor **full-speed charging of multiple devices**. *(as long as any individual port can charge at 100W if left alone, I'm happy if connecting multiple high-draw devices slows it down)*

Answer (score 3):

Nothing with more than 2 ports exists as far as I know. (2017-07)
Even the chips to make it are limited to 2 ports as far as I can tell.
Wanted this for a while myself for a group of pixels and other devices that are all type C.
They are getting closer: Lifepowr has an indiegogo with 100W type c dual ports. https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/lifepowr-a3-world-s-1st-usb-c-power-delivery-pack-battery-powerbank#/

Comment: I see you signed up to answer — that's a good link! It's a battery-pack, instead of a wall-wart, but it's definitely something up my alley. (Now, if only they did a version with something more like 60Ah, as opposed to only 25Ah …)

Answer (score 0):

In September 2017, the pickings are still slim for high-wattage multi-C-port USB chargers.  Google provides a low-wattage two-C-port charger here :
https://store.google.com/us/product/usb_c_dual_port_charger?hl=en-US

Most phones which will charge happily with A-to-C cables from traditional high-wattage multi-A-port chargers.  I suspect consumers will try and plug multiple 87W MacBook Pros into their 100W chargers, and blame the charger for not keeping up.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a true 100W USB-C dedicated charger that has no other function (no other ports stealing the power, all 100W is in the one USB-C, and not a docking station), then I suggest the Wacom MobileStudio Pro charger:

https://buywacom.com.au/products/accessories/cables-and-power/power-adapter-for-mobilestudio-pro.html

If any visitors are in Australia, I believe it has RCM certification for use here. Also, unfortunately, the cord is not detachable. Laptop manufacturers who make these chargers tend to hold on to what they are used of, which is laptop chargers with hardwired cords. This means the cord cannot be replaced if damaged, it cannot be swapped for cables of different lengths, and if anybody actually cares, it would make it impossible to fast charge an iPad with the USB-C to Lightning cable (the only way to charge at full rate right now).

---

As for multiple ports, there are ones with 8x 60W USB-C PD ports. Also ones with six and four, plus a cabinet with 20x PD ports (up to 60W each, but shared with 120V per bank and 4 banks for total of 480W):

- https://www.coolgear.com/product-category/usb-c-products/usb-c-chargers
- https://www.coolgear.com/news/new-usb-c-power-delivery-products-coolgear.html

Comment: Can you break this up into two different answers please? That way the community can vote on each piece separately. Also according to OP's profile, they are from the US, so your last paragraph isn't exactly useless.

Comment: Thanks for the info you brought to share, @Karatekid430. That brand looks promising, especially because it's rackmount!

Comment: Now, In the same ‘it's not for you, it's for the majority-rest of possible readers’ spirit, I think I'll address your edits below — despite the fact I'm sure you've immediately sworn off StackExchange. That's not how we do things around here. While we try to maintain the *spirit* and *content* of both questions and answers, all content on these sites is subject to editing by other users with more experience on the site. That is regardless of whether you came here desiring your commentary be edited — again, we edit for the many, not the few.

Comment: (I offer the above primarily in the spirit of ‘[leave a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) and explain *why*, if you vote something down’ — another community norm, around here!)